# Received Access Request for Unshared Google Drive Folder

Tags: google-drive

I received an access request for an unshared folder. I don't know how this folder link could have gone public as I have never--under any circumstances--shared this folder. It is still unshared:

[image]

**My theory:**
Someone has created a bot that tries different google drive URLs and sends an access request if a valid URL is found. Is this reasonable/plausible? I can't imagine why someone would want to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

The person who requested the file is a new employee for the old company I worked for. My google account is no longer logged in but the chrome history still remains. This person must have accessed the file via history. As my account is no longer logged in, drive decided to request access.

Comment: If any veteran community members wants me to close this question, let me know with a comment. Who knows? It might be helpful to someone eventually.